# Word macro doesn't work as soon as I use With...End With

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've experienced something weird today while making a macro. 
I have a lot of documents using the same template so my macro scan one of them and do some stuff depending on the title (level and number). Anyway, it doesn't realy matter. Here is the code

```
Private Sub MyMacro()
     Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

        While Not (Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString, 1) = "3")  'go to Title n°3
            Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToNext
        Wend

        While ((Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString, 1) = "3"))  'do not go further than title n°3
            'if the curent title level is 2 and ended with 1,2 or 3 then
            If Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 2 And Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListValue < 4 Then
                'Do Something
            ElseIf Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 3 And Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListValue <> 4 And Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString, 4) = "3.1." Then
                'Do something else
            ElseIf Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 4 And Left(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString, 5) = "3.2.1" Then
                'and a last one
            End If
            'go to the next title in the document
            Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToNext
        Wend
End Sub
```

This code works but as you can see it's not very easy to read... 
I try to insert a `With...End With` statement to improve this.

```
    With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat
        'isert here the same code as before with only .ListString and .ListLevelNumber
    End With
```

Unfortunately, this makes my `While` loops failed, and I can't figure out why.
I monitored the outputs and it appears `ListString` always return the first title (where the macro starts). 
Have you got any idea why?

Thanks a lot in advance

Regards

EDIT : 
The final code is supposed to look like this

```
Private Sub MyMacro()
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

With Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat
    While Not (Left(.ListString, 1) = "3")  'go to Title n°3
        Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToNext
    Wend

    While ((Left(.ListString, 1) = "3"))  'do not go further than title n°3
        'if the curent title level is 2 and ended with 1,2 or 3 then
        If .ListLevelNumber = 2 And .ListValue < 4 Then
            'Do Something
        ElseIf .ListLevelNumber = 3 And .ListValue <> 4 And Left(.ListString, 4) = "3.1." Then
            'Do something else
        ElseIf .ListLevelNumber = 4 And Left(.ListString, 5) = "3.2.1" Then
            'and a last one
        End If
        'go to the next title in the document
        Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToHeading, which:=wdGoToNext
    Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As to making your code easier to read: Work with a `Range` or even a `ListFormat` object instead of a Selection object and that will make things not only easier to read, but more accurate, more efficient and more pleasant for the user to look at the screen during execution.

Comment: I'm not very used to word-vba, I don't know how to use Range object yet, but I'll work on it.
How do you propose to use them here? 

I'll edit my first post to show the entire code with the `With...End With`
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason what you've attempted is not working is that `With` is always referencing `Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range` *at the time this line is called* and testing whether the left-most character is "3". Since the number at the beginning of that first paragraph never changes, the code doesn't work as you hope. If you put `Debug.Print .ListString` just before the `Wend` you can see that it never changes.

Here's a different way to write your code to make it easier to follow, just to give you an idea how to work with a `Range` object. It loops all the numbered ("list") paragraphs in the document and will skip any non-numbered paragraphs. This may not be optimal in your case - since you don't give any details about the document, it's hard to know.

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim paras As Word.ListParagraphs
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim lvl As Long, listVal As Long

    Set paras = ActiveDocument.ListParagraphs

    For Each para In paras
        Set rng = para.Range
        If Left(rng.ListFormat.ListString, 1) = "3" Then
            lvl = rng.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
            listVal = rng.ListFormat.ListValue
            Select Case lvl
                Case 2
                    If listVal < 4 Then
                        Debug.Print "Case 2: lvl " & lvl & "; listVal " & listVal
                    End If
                Case 3
                    If listVal <> 4 And Left(rng.ListFormat.ListString, 4) = "3.1." Then
                        Debug.Print "Case 3: lvl " & lvl & "; listVal " & listVal
                    End If
                Case 4
                    If Left(rng.ListFormat.ListString, 5) = "3.2.1" Then
                        Debug.Print "Case 4: lvl " & lvl & "; listVal " & listVal
                    End If
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print "Case else"
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to avoid looping on all paragraphe with a `For Each` loop since my document is quite long (I can't give you more details about it, sorry. It's a professionnal document that I'm not allowed to talk about here) but maybe this is the most efficient way to do.
I'll try to work out something thanks to the exemple you provided me and let you know if it works.
Once again thanks a lot !

Comment: you're welcome... The other thought that went through my mind, if you want to target paragraphs formatted with a Heading style, is `Find` - you can use that to search style formatting. That will let you "jump" to each Heading 1 (or 2, or 3) paragraph.

Comment: @Ezor It (finally) occurred to me that there is a more efficient way to loop: Word can "look at" only paragraphs that have numbering. I've edited the Answer with that info.

Comment: That actually a pretty good solution in this case. It will perfectly do the trick ! 
FYI, it decreases the amount of comparisons by 16 in some of my documents !